# How do "cabal-dev" and "cabal sandbox init" relate to each other?

Tags: haskell, cabal

It seems that I am missing something. As far as I understand `cabal sandbox init` says that starting from the current folder and all sub-folders all `cabal install` commands are scoped to a sandbox. So everything outside this folder is not in a sandbox.

What's the purpose of cabal-dev then? Should I use `cabal install` or `cabal-dev install` in a sandbox?

Comment: See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/107979/focus=107980

Comment: tl;dr: if in doubt, use built-in cabal sandboxes instead of cabal-dev.

Answer (score 21):

TLDR, `cabal-dev` was an initial solution for sandboxing and `cabal sandbox` is the fully integrated realization.

Until a few months ago, there was no pleasant way to sandbox builds with `cabal`. This was a huge problem for any library maintainer or really anyone who might worry about dependency conflicts. To solve this, a few people but together a tool called `cabal-dev`. It supplemented `cabal` and added some ability to sandbox.

Now after this existing for a few years, in version 1.18, `cabal` has gained sandboxes! This means that we can switch from using `cabal` + `cabal-dev` to just `cabal` since `cabal` has now subsumed `cabal-dev`.

In addition, because sandboxes are fully integrated into cabal, they play nicely with other cabal features, like `cabal repl` which is just impossible for `cabal-dev`.

Finally, recent chatter on the Haskell-Cafe mailing list suggests that `cabal-dev` is not likely to be maintained much longer so aside from 1-2 current bugs in `cabal sandbox` there's no reason not to switch.

Comment: Exactly right.  Rogan has been telling everyone to move from cabal-dev to cabal, and I don't expect anyone to be maintaining cabal-dev any longer.